# Wifi on HP Envy Sleekbook 6-111nr not working

Tags: wireless, hp, ralink

I purchased a HP Sleekbook with Windows 8, enabled legacy OS in BIOS and installed Ubuntu 12.10.

I can not get the wireless to work.

Here is my hardware list from HP.com

```
Product Name                6-1111nr
Product Number              C2K94UA
Microprocessor              2.1GHz up to 2.6GHz AMD A6-4455M Accelerated Processor
Microprocessor Cache        1MB L2 Cache
Memory                      4GB DDR3 SDRAM (1 DIMM)
Memory Max                  Maximum supported = 16GB
Memory Slots                2 user accessible
Video Graphics              AMD Radeon HD 7500G Discrete-Class graphics and up to 2036MB total graphics memory
Display                     15.6-inch diagonal HD BrightView LED-backlit display (1366x768)
Hard Drive                  500GB 5400RPM hard drive with HP ProtectSmart Hard Drive Protection
Network Card                10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet LAN (RJ-45 connector)
Wireless Connectivity       802.11b/g/n WLAN 
Bluetooth
Sound                       Beats Audio dual speakers and a subwoofer
Keyboard                    Full-size island-style keyboard
Pointing Device             HP Imagepad supporting multi-touch gestures with on/off button.
External Ports              Multi-format digital media card reader for Secure Digital cards and Multimedia cards 
2 SuperSpeed USB 3.0
1 Universal Serial Bus (USB) 2.0
1 HDMI
1 RJ-45 (LAN)
1 Headphone
1 Microphone in
Dimensions                  14.72 in (W) x 9.95 in (D) x 0.78 in (H)
Weight                      4.53 lb
Power                       65W AC adapter
4-Cell 60WHr 4.1 Ah lithium-ion polymer battery
ID Mech Description         HP TrueVision HD Webcam with integrated dual array digital microphone
```

**iwconfig:**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**lsmod:**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 46620  0 
bnep                   18141  2 
bluetooth             209249  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32689  0 
ppdev                  17074  0 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70210  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32049  1 
snd_hda_intel          33492  5 
snd_hda_codec         134213  3 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               76750  0 
snd_hwdep              17699  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96668  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
radeon                895730  4 
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30513  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_core         32852  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61555  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
videodev              120310  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_timer              29426  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ttm                    83596  1 radeon
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
joydev                 17458  0 
kvm                   414071  0 
drm_kms_helper         49113  1 radeon
snd                    78921  20 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
drm                   288721  6 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
soundcore              15048  1 snd
psmouse                95595  0 
snd_page_alloc         18485  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
aesni_intel            51038  0 
cryptd                 20404  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
k10temp                13127  0 
video                  19336  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
hp_wmi                 18049  0 
hp_accel               25977  0 
sparse_keymap          13891  1 hp_wmi
lis3lv02d              19830  1 hp_accel
i2c_piix4              13168  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13414  1 radeon
microcode              22804  0 
mac_hid                13206  0 
wmi                    19071  1 hp_wmi
input_polldev          13897  1 lis3lv02d
binfmt_misc            17501  1 
lp                     17760  0 
parport                46346  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usb_storage            48839  0 
hid_generic            12541  0 
usbhid                 46987  0 
hid                   100411  2 hid_generic,usbhid
r8169                  61651  0
```

**ifconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:34:97:17:5c:68  
          inet addr:192.168.0.109  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8634:97ff:fe17:5c68/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13460 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11265410 (11.2 MB)  TX bytes:1827803 (1.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5670 (5.6 KB)  TX bytes:5670 (5.6 KB)
```

Sorry about that. I am still trying to get a hold of all this.

```
william@william-HP-Sleekbook:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
02:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3298]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
```

Hope this is what you were after. Thanks!

Comment: soory we need `lspci` result.

Comment: More specifically: `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"`

Comment: Here is the lspci output:                                                                            william@william-HP-Sleekbook:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
02:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3298]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]

Comment: @Cody Can you put the output in your answer? The formatting is badly broken from fitting it into a comment (which doesn't support line breaks). After running the command again and pasting the output into your question, you can use the `<$>` tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar to format it properly.

Comment: Was this problem solved finally? I'm having a same problem.

Comment: Yep, solved by installing Windows 7 Ultimate instead of Ubuntu.